# Why does nothing appear on the Pokemon Go map in the Diego Garcia Navy Support Facilty in the Indian Ocean?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

Why is it like that? it's just the map and that's it, no Pokestops, Gyms, nor Pokemon except for the starters, I've been walking around for lots of miles in search for Pokemon but I haven't found one, why is that?

Comment: i dont know for sure but may be like people un rural areas. you are too apart from land (big land). or could it be some bugs, server errors, gps malfunctioning ... etc.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This, to me, seems like a perfectly fine thing to ask. Why are people hampered based on their location.

Comment: @j4k3 - Most likely because of the spelling/grammar and for assuming that we're Niantic or the Pokemon Go team. I have cleaned up the question and removed the request for Niantic/PoGo team to answer.

Comment: For those reading this question, here is some context of [just how remote](http://goo.gl/maps/Xmg7WnrL7c82) Diego Garcia is.

Comment: Just like you, I have never encountered any Pokemon on Diego Garcia in the wild. The only Pokemon I saw were the starters and the ones that appeared from the effect of incense. I tried traveling from the south part of the Island (Fire Dept) to the villages (Seabreeze and Palmsville) and still get nothing. I hope that one of these days our area will be supported by the servers...

Answer (score 5):

There are two possibilities. The first is this is caused by server issues. In this case, wait a few hours and come back.

The other is that there are simply no pokemon or gyms in your area. It's based on traffic so if you're at a secluded military facility, there's unlikely to be anything around. Niantic (not us) have also removed a lot of stops and gyms from military bases since they aren't accessible to the public.

Comment: i already use my 2 incense, and i caught rares, but now using my data even though a traveled around the island not even a single pokemon come out, :( so i will never have the chance to be stronger now?

Comment: @user161838 If incense is working but nothing else, it's definitely the area. Guess you won't be able to play until you get shore leave.

Comment: until i leave this military base??

Comment: @user161838 Yes. Though I wouldn't recommending deserting just to catch pokemon.

Comment: this is my stress reliever here, any chance that i can catch pokemon without using incense? there are no pokestops here so i'll just buy to the app store to play this game

Comment: @user161838 Even if you had pokestops, you wouldn't be able to get an incense or lure from it. So buying incense is probably the way to go (if you want to get stronger), guess you are just unlucky, sorry guy :(

Comment: I'm rather confident that military bases block natural spawns.

Answer (score 4):

Military bases are considered [no-spawn zones](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rp7kz/psa_no_pok%C3%A9mon_on_military_bases/) in order to keep the base secure and to keep trespassers from having motivation to enter a base.

You may still use Incense to force a Pokemon to spawn, but  your rates and quality of spawns are likely to be low.

If you're upset about this, it's probably best to ask your commanding officer to ask Niantic for an exception to this rule for your base.